# PhpStorm Warnings on incorrect objects (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, phpoffice

I have been cleaning up some PhpStorm warnings using PHPDoc and in some cases there are objects referenced incorrectly. Here's an example:

```
$Title = $currentSlide->createRichTextShape();
```

CreateRichTextShape() returns as RichText as seen here:

```
/**
 * Create rich text shape
 *
 * @return \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Shape\RichText
 */
public function createRichTextShape()
{
    $shape = new RichText();
    $this->addShape($shape);
    return $shape;
}
```

This all works fine.

Then I try to call a function within RichText such as:

```
$textRun = $Title->createTextRun( 'Title' );
```

However, when hovering over the code I receive this warning:

[image: this warning.]

PhpStorm thinks `CreateRichTextShape()` is returning an `AbstractShape` when it is actually returning a `RichText`, so it can't find the function within `AbstractShape` even though it exists and is documented correctly.

Note that there are no actual errors in this code - it runs fine. Just want to get rid of the warnings.

Comment: Need more info / a sample project perhaps. Based purely on info you have provided (PHPDoc for `createRichTextShape()`) it should not report `AbstractShape`. Right now it looks like you have much more code there that may create such "interference" (e.g. assigning multiple different values to the same variable / reusing variable / different typehint in another place etc). May also be worth trying `File | Invalidate Cache...` and restart IDE (just in case). Better code sample is needed. I also suggest invoking `View | Quick Definition` on variables/methods etc to see what IDE thinks about them.

Comment: It's Laravel project .. you may be using DI/CI (e.g. `app('some-service')->` or alike) and it may have different (more generic) typehint etc.

Comment: @LazyOne I tried both of those attempts to no avail. Quick definition defined the variable as AbstractShape when the method was returning a RichText. Ended up simply adding a PHPDoc to declare the variable as a RichText. Looked something like this: `/** @var RichText $Title */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least regarding Laravel Projects, you can clear this up in PhpStorm by adding

`/** @var RichText $Title */`

before the variable/method.